# Has Zwift ever publicly addressed the issue of bot farms accumulating XP/kit/drops on accounts for sale?

Tags: zwift

Please refer to the screen-captures here:

[image]

This user passed me on Epic KOM and proceeded to continue riding at 5.7w/kg (sic) for the complete duration of time that I could see their details. It went on for longer than the almost ~9km difference you see in these two screen captures.

While W/kg at that number for those durations is possible, **does anyone else smell what I'm stepping in?**

1. They are not using ERG mode, and yet the power output had zero
   deviation*.
2. This effort would be Grand Tour level after 262km already in the saddle.
3. They did not get the Epic KOM jersey at the top of the hill, i.e. 'someone' even faster did (!?)
4. They use a name that I cannot find in the companion app.

I expect this is a 'bot' where a power meter hack has been used to collect XP, drops, Tron Bikes and similar for eventual sale later.

As Zwift describes its app as a game I would assume they should be concerned about the effect that users like this have in demotivating other (human) users in the gamified aspects such as KOM jersey hunting, kit unlocks and other general 'levelling up'.

I don't see evidence of any concern online.

**Has Zwift ever publicly addressed the issue of bot farms accumulating XP/kit/drops on accounts for sale?**

(* it maybe possible they are running ERG mode via another device, but either way, it's not hard to see more obvious abuses and less likely power outputs - *just use the game* - no photos, but for instance I've also seen back to back 1000km rides at a dead steady 350W.)

**Edit** - could be relevant:

[image]

**Edit #2** - example added:

https://www.fiverr.com/anelsi/get-you-to-level-50-or-the-tron-bike-on-zwift?fbclid=IwAR0ZO1clMJZHZKEMNqMvyo_IINjHa1PEP8f_U1-LLEnE0PE2_swvgVm7dWI

[image]
[image]

Comment: I appreciate the effort but I don't think somebody from Zwift officially will respond here when there's https://forums.zwift.com, so their own community/forum. I just searched for terms _cheating_ and _bot_ there and they're not too open about it there, either. Unless you are racing, I personally wouldn't be bothered too much by what others are achieving in Zwift. There is the well-documented rubber-band bug where you go ~42 kph all the time in small groups - so, freeriding isn't a good comparison, anyway.

Comment: See, for example https://thehustle.co/one-mans-quest-to-end-cheating-in-virtual-cycling/amp/  and https://www.dcrainmaker.com/2022/02/zwifts-bans-whistleblower-deeper.html  Zwift only cares about cheaters in the top competing divisions, not in the low ranks.

Comment: I like one statement stolen from their forms: _The only person you’re really competing with is yourself_ - for the gamification aspect, I think most of it (perhaps except from KOM/jerseys) isn't really impaired by freeride cheaters, you need to grind your own XP to get unlocks, anyway.

Comment: @DoNuT I just tried linking this page in the Zwift forums - but they have disabled links ‍♂. I'll wait until google finds it then post appropriate search terms. As for XP, I agree you have to accumulate your own, but a for a 'currency' to have any value it needs an element of scarcity. I'm not an economist but bot farms are basically pushing inflation and devaluing a commodity.

Comment: What’s the actual problem here? Also: Do you expect Zwift employee to create an SE account and respond to this for your benefit alone? If they were going to communicate with you, it’d be through official channels. My advice: put on fenders and go ride outside. If that’s not an option, switch to TrainerDay. It’s less than 1/3rd the price of Zwift

Comment: @PaulH The problem is right there in the question: "the effect that users like this have in demotivating other (human) users in the gamified aspects such as KOM jersey hunting, kit unlocks and other general 'levelling up". Ask yourself, if the gamification and the commodity that it creates i.e. XP/kit/etc. (as laughable as you may find that) *wasn't* desirable then there wouldn't be a market for people to set up bot farms like this in the first place. And yes, it would be nice if a Zwift employee could front up here. And finally, the fact that it may or may not bother *you* isn't my concern :)

Comment: So what’s the question you want this community to answer?

Comment: @PaulH Let me copy and paste things for you again: "Has Zwift ever publicly addressed the issue of bot farms accumulating XP/kit/drops on accounts for sale?" And then: "I'd like this Q&A to be an open forum for Zwift to respond with the steps that they're taking to address XP farming bots. If Zwift are not forthcoming here perhaps they have addressed it elsewhere. Links, screen-captures, etc. of examples appreciated."

Comment: Like I already said, the likelihood Zwift employees creating official accounts to respond here is approximately 0.

Comment: @PaulH I’m struggling to understand your motivations here right now. Do I really have to copy and paste something I've already copied and pasted? Please don't respond, I'd appreciate that.

Comment: I'm just trying to let you know that you're probably not going to get what you want and Bikes.SE likely isn't the best avenue for it.

Comment: I've edited the question to not include specifying Zwift as being the preferred answerer. It's more general now, just looking for any evidence of official discussion regarding the topic.

Comment: Looking in my crystal ball, I see that the main motivation is just complaining in public location where Zwift-employed moderator can't delete the post. As for the question as written at the moment, my gut feeling is that the answer is "no" but it's difficult to prove a negative.

Comment: I just found a recent article about competitive cheating and this suggest they mainly care about their top-league races to be clean and increasingly less down the tiers and into freeriding: https://thehustle.co/one-mans-quest-to-end-cheating-in-virtual-cycling/

Comment: @DoNuT Vladimir linked that above, the DC RainMaker article is a bit more succinct. Wow, it's pretty damning stuff huh ?? If they're going down paths like that regarding weight doping then any interest improving the gamified (non-racing) aspects are going to get ZERO traction.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter too much: Some people just want to ride their bikes while it is cold and dark outside. 90% of my rides are structured workouts to get my winter training in, I don't mind freeriding or the gamification aspect too much - that stopped when I unlocked a frame of my brand but since then, XP and KOMs are just a byproduct - I would imagine that's the same for many older folks and those who used a static trainer, before.

Comment: If that's the prevailing attitude there is a solution available to Zwift where they simply drop the gamified aspects. 

Comment: I'm of the opinion that this is a useful question.  Zwift is used by a lot of cyclists, and this question and any potential answers could be informative about Zwift's environment.  The motivation behind the question isn't relevant, IMO.

Comment: The title is pure speculation. The existence of riders with implausible power numbers does not imply that there are bot farms creating accounts for sale. If there is more evidence (like sites offering this service / accounts), sure. But not like this.

Comment: @linac 300W for 1000km, it doesn't take long to see examples like this. I'll see if I can find examples. I didn't think I'd need to...

Comment: @LamarLatrell *300W for 1000km* that's the what user:linac is questioning. They're questioning whether the juiced accounts are actually being sold to other users.

Comment: @PaulH Thanks for all your efforts here in keeping me updated and on topic. As for buying an account I'm not that way inclined, but now I'm curious maybe I'll have a deeper look this evening. In the meantime there was this: https://road.cc/content/news/267266-zwift-national-champion-stripped-title-because-he-didnt-earn-tron-bike-he-rode

Comment: @PaulH Didn't take long to find this: https://global.discourse-cdn.com/gozwift/original/4X/d/0/3/d0305063813ad8f3a5c44cc99cd6d547710e7a9a.jpeg  etc. etc.

Comment: @linac Please see examples added to the body of the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: **Yes** - Zwift has addressed this in various statements and their terms of usage.

Zwift's [Terms of Services](https://support.zwift.com/en_us/terms-of-service-HJt7VBYyH) disallow cheating, my interpretation is that this is covered by *Section 5a, paragraph XI*

> Develop or use any applications that interact with our Platform without our prior written authorization, including any cheats, mods or matchmaking services or applications that emulate or redirect the communication protocols used by Zwift in any way, including for unauthorized play over the Internet, network play, or as part of content aggregation networks;

*5a, paragraph IV* very likely prohibits all reselling of accounts including unlocks etc.

> Sell, resell or otherwise commercially use our Platform by (i) displaying the Platform in a commercial setting (like a cyber cafe, gaming center or other commercial establishment) (which is encouraged with the right display and synergies and with Zwift’s prior written authorization), (ii) selling, licensing or renting any items you purchase via the Platform (including in-game virtual items or physical products) or access to your account to any third party; (iii) performing activities on the Platform for others for compensation; or (iv) using the Platform for any “esports” or group competition sponsored, promoted or facilitated by any commercial or non-profit entity (which may also be encouraged depending on the circumstances and with Zwift’s prior written authorization);

There is a [case](https://www.dcrainmaker.com/2019/10/british-cycling-strips-zwift-championship-winner-for-cheating.html) of a British pro cyclist who used an ANT+ emulation device to farm the famous [tron bike](https://zwiftinsider.com/unlock-the-tron-bike-in-zwift/) as preparation for a race and got fined and suspended from racing by British Cycling, Zwift supported the action taken in a statement given from the CEO:

> Good governance and integrity are the cornerstone of Zwift Esports.  We are committed to utilising all the resources we have available to police competition at the very highest level and ensure fair competition.  We fully support the action taken by British Cycling in the case against Cameron Jeffers.”

It is not clear if he had been banned from the platform as well back then but it is clear that bots/cheating are considered violating their Terms Of Service. So, also farming and reselling accounts is clearly illegal.

For their Zwift Cycling Esports events, there are extensive [rules](https://zwift.com/p/zwift-cycling-esports-rules/) to validate your performances, for example

- A weigh-in video
- Recording a secondary power source (powermeter pedals/cranks with a head unit)

When it comes to non-racing, I haven't found any articles how they detect anomalies but my guess in the year 2023 with machine learning at a very high level is that they indeed have some technology in place, the mentioned British cyclist discarded his cheating rides so that nobody notices.

Their racing leagues are even supervised by a "Performance Verification Board" that reviews athlete performance with regards to manipulation. That sounds like a very manual task that cannot be scaled to the whole platform, so there is definitely emphasis on legitimity of their professional races.

For "normal" users and as an observer of suspicious/cheating behavior, you can indeed report users via the companion app but I wouldn't expect better response time and feedback quality than on comparable online platforms.

Answer (score 6):

Donut is correct that Zwift *de jure* prohibits this sort of activity. The issue being raised is that *de facto*, some people slip under the radar. I think that Zwift has taken at least some action, but there is still cheating and exploiting going on. I think there are structural issues that mean that Zwift isn't likely to be able/willing to come down hard on the issue. Even if they did, they couldn't completely eliminate the issues.

I don't work in the software industry or in Zwift. Some observations below are based on my experience as an ordinary Zwifter (I've been anywhere from fairly high in Cat B to the bottom of that category) plus as a player of one other online game.

### Definitions

I'll use the term *cheat* to refer to outright cheating like Cameron Jeffers did. This is when you do something like use an ANT+ stick to mimic the fact that you're riding, or you manipulate your power meter data, or something blatant.

I'll say *exploit* for when a player triggers a bug to give themselves an advantage. Note that you can *accidentally* use an exploit. You can of course use an exploit deliberately as well, but there is a gray area between deliberate and accidental! Related, your equipment can be inaccurate (e.g. calibrated wrong and you genuinely didn't know), which isn't a situation normally found in online gaming but which is a bit like an exploit in that it can happen inadvertently, but can be deliberately misused. Or, again, there can be a gray zone - for example, we all should diligently update our weights, but you bet that sometimes this slips your mind. I bet people are more likely to update after a weight loss than after weight gain.

In Zwift, *free riding* means people just riding outside of a formal race. You can hunt segments, you can go for your best time up the Alpe du Zwift - in other words, you can potentially treat a free ride like a race. I'll say race to mean any race or major event where some people race it, e.g. the Tour of Watopia. Think of these like you would a marathon or Gran Fondo.

*Technical debt* applies to many software platforms. It occurs when you push ahead to add code for new features now, but the code becomes uglier and harder to maintain. More technical debt means a higher probability of incurring bugs. The relevance will become obvious.

*Organizational capacity* means the ability of an organization to achieve a goal. For example, the more people you have, the higher your capacity - but only up to a point! You have to coordinate between teams, which incurs overhead. Again, the relevance will become obvious later.

### Surveillance in racing

While people still slip through the cracks, Zwift has a Performance Verification Board. They can do things like monitor riders power curves for performances that are outside of the rider's normal or out of probable human limits. For example, [Eddy Hoole](https://road.cc/content/news/banned-racer-tries-mywhoosh-gets-disqualified-300253) put out 8.5 W/kg for 4 minutes in a Zwift race. Everyone watching saw that as an extreme performance. He got banned. Or, because elite riders must dual record (use an accurate power meter connected to a second head unit, and submit both records), they can monitor for discrepancies between the records or other signs of manipulation.

The issue is that this monitoring is labor-intensive. It applies to elite riders. I guess they probably can sanction Cat Ds through Bs, but I doubt they do it often if at all. The method doesn't scale well to the plebeians.

People who are extremely into Zwift racing as amateurs may remember [Luciano Pollastri](https://www.dcrainmaker.com/2022/02/zwifts-bans-whistleblower-deeper.html), who publicized an exploit in a fit of pique - to be fair, he said that Zwift had not been responsive to him raising the issue and/or other issues before, so he quickly publicized the exploit he found before seriously consulting with Zwift. My impression as an observer is that he had a point. Zwift banned him on the grounds that they didn't want people publicizing exploits. This is a potentially reasonable stance.

However, I believe many observers would agree that Zwift are slow to respond to issues of fair racing in general. If you do this too much, I think it renders your stance about publicizing exploits unreasonable.

### Surveillance for ordinary riders

Donut states that

> When it comes to non-racing, I haven't found any articles how they detect anomalies but my guess in the year 2023 with machine learning at a very high level is that they indeed have some technology in place, [Cameron Jeffers] discarded his cheating rides so that nobody notices.

I doubt that this is feasible. The issue with machine learning is that someone has to program the computer and monitor the algorithm's performance. The algorithm will produce false positives and false negatives, so the programmer also has to optimize the algorithm's performance. Then Zwift would have to adjudicate any proposed sanctions - they won't need to abide by the standard of due process in US law or other countries laws, but they will need to have some procedure that gets at the notion of due process or else they'll lose customers. I doubt they can automatically detect cheaters and ban them in batches. The process has to be more complex.

I can think of an SQL query that someone could run to catch this particular instance. For example, you could query rides which averaged more than 4 W/kg, and where the normalized power (NP) over the ride was exactly equal to the average power, and that were over a certain length (e.g. 100km). That is, NP is an estimate of what average wattage you could have maintained to go at the same speed. Going over your threshold is more costly to the body than going under it. Anyway, this is like looking for a variability index of exactly 1. The issue is that you'll miss some cheaters - you'll probably have a bunch of false negatives, even if you don't get any false positives.

And you have to run the query periodically, then collect the results, then do then same for all the other queries you developed, and finally hand the query results off to a manager, all while doing all the other tasks you were assigned. If Zwift are serious about acting on this, they will need to find some sort of process that at least minimizes the likelihood of unfairly sanctioning someone. For example, they'll probably need to review the rider's other rides as well. You could rely on machine learning, but we don't have artificial general intelligence yet, so it's not just press a button and let the computer take care of everything. Machine learning algorithms require a human to develop and monitor them, and this requires a lot more skill than running simple SQL queries.

### The structural issue

I think that game companies have a commercial incentive to expand their game by adding features. This is understandable as they seek to maximize their profits. However, everyone has limited organizational capacity. Thus, I suspect that expansion will often take priority over gaming integrity issues, as well as other things like responding to user requests for features, eliminating bugs, and streamlining code. Additionally, more features means a more complex code base. Hence, the amount of and/or impact of technical debt probably increases non-linearly with the code base, meaning that you get more bugs and/or possible exploits.

Also, specific to Zwift, they've stated that racers are a minority of the user base. Therefore, they're likely to have other more pressing issues to address before they deal with the racers' needs. And game integrity is more of an issue for racers than non-racers. The Zwift racing community seems to feel like many previous requests were ignored or acknowledged but not acted on for a long time - enforcing racing category W/kg boundaries was one of them. It seems to me like Zwift doesn't have enough organizational capacity to deal with all the issues they need to, and they aren't likely to devote organizational capacity to issues affecting a minority of their users.

Finally, competition does tend to force companies to improve. However, there isn't a lot of direct competition to Zwift. RGT could have been a credible competitor, but its user base was [much smaller than Zwift's](https://www.dcrainmaker.com/2023/10/wahoo-fitness-to-shut-down-rgt-virtual-cycling-app.html), and as if to illustrate my point Wahoo announced that they are closing it. None of the remaining platforms has gathered the same mass as Zwift. Hence, if a new user thinks about which platform to start with, they are probably more likely to go to Zwift since a lot of users are there, and the company probably has the most resources to continue development.

### Conclusion

I think that most observers agree that sports authorities are always a step behind the cheaters, be this for drugs or online gaming cheats and exploits. Moreover, there are the structural issues that I identified above, which might worsen the problem for platforms like Zwift.

Thus, Zwift have probably taken at least some steps to address bots like these and other fairness issues. However, they're not likely to have an automated solution that's scalable. You can manually report users like this. The issue is that most people won't know they can do this, or the user might pass too far ahead of them by the time they've navigated to the reporting function, or they're at VO2max power and don't have the cognitive function to report the rider. Also, we don't know how reliably Zwift acts on reported riders. If you ask the Zwift racing forum, I bet you'll hear people complain that they've reported people and seen no result. If investigating the issue is too hard, then I suspect the tech support staff will give up for more pressing matters, or they'll report things up to the next level but those folks do the same.

I think that Supercell, which is famous for Clash of Clans and Clash Royale, has a gaming integrity team separate from each game's community manager and programmers. (Disclosure, I sometimes play Boom Beach.) The gaming integrity team can sanction cheats across all the company's platforms. Zwift might empower their Performance Verification Board to act on issues that affect the general player base. However, that board [only had three members in 2020](https://zwiftinsider.com/zwift-bans-two-riders/). They would need additional organizational capacity to act on issues like the one raised. That means that money's got to come from somewhere, or else you need to take people who are willing to volunteer to do this - but they're going to have day jobs or they will have day jobs one day.

Comment: + Some of these points raised (machine learning platforms, development, support & human review) are also a massive cost factor in addition to the "core" platform and they pushed lots of investor money into hardware products (which seems to be one major focus of extending the platform).

Comment: I had a conversation with Zwift's CEO and chief technologist years ago about cheating and detection (I had done some detection of manipulated cycling data, so they were put in contact with me). At that time, there were several things they could do but they were all relatively resource-heavy so they were more appropriate for focusing on individuals rather than as a general screening tool. Back then we were more concerned about cheating during racing than in the "normal" game. I think that's still true.

Comment: @R.Chung resource heavy? Maybe if you're constantly polling W/kg over durations and comparing them to a World Class power curve, but it seems that the typical bot you see is much clumsier. Just a couple of accumulating variables and conditionals are all that is required. Jeez, I'd even be happy if were applied post ride, they'd be identified pretty swiftly... Either way. it's not like I'm using extra sensory perception when I 'see' them myself, it's as basic as 'hey, they've been doing crazy W/kg for how long now?? Wow!'. If I can notice it day to day, and I'm not even looking for it...

Comment: @LamarLatrell If it is not in racing, they don't care. It is as simple as that.

Comment: @LamarLatrell You can easily write an SQL query to catch the bots you describe. You will miss some of them depending on the cutoff values you select. Then you have to send the query to a manager who has to then find and administer some sort of due process. Then you have to run that query regularly, along with all the other queries you thought of, along with doing your regular job. I agree Zwift should do this, but this strains their organizational capacity.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава You're discounting the possibility that Zwift has determined that cheating like this actually increases their user base and/or revenues.  "Gee, we didn't know all those ad page views we charged you for were to bots."  It's even true **if they don't look**.  "LaLaLaLaLa!  No bots here!!!"

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I'm aware. What I want is everyone else who cares to be aware. *Then* there is a small chance they may do something about it.